# How to go to specific date on Laravel Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I'm using Maddhatter fullcalendar composer.
And I want to make input that allow you to go to specific date.

[image: like this]

I just search in [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/gotoDate) and I found `gotoDate` function. How can I use that function on laravel? or is there any solution to make this happen?

Comment: What did you do for it?

Comment: redo the question dont be lazzy ask better more details add code.

Comment: I'm really sorry, actually this is my first question at stackoverflow (><"),, I don't add the codes because I just already make function to view calendar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do it in Laravel at all...Laravel/PHP code runs server-side. The Laravel code just renders some HTML and JavaScript into the browser to get fullCalendar to work. Therefore you can do this entirely client-side using JavaScript, and disregard the Laravel part. The only thing you need to take note of from your PHP code is the ID you give to the calendar - replace the `calendar` ID in my code below with the ID you've used.

HTML:

```
Date: <input type="date" id="dateField"/>
<button type="button" id="dateBtn">Go to date</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#dateBtn").click(function(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate", $("#dateField").val());
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/826/ for a working demo.

Comment: Thankyou for mentioning the calendar ID! (><), I just try it after I manage to get the calendar ID at the controller 

`$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)->setOptions([
            'eventLimit' => 4,
        ])->setId('scheduler')` 

 And then take it to javascript as you say,, 

`$("#dateBtn").click(function(){
    $("#calendar-scheduler").fullCalendar("gotoDate", $("#dateField").val());
});` 

It worked now thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn the date into a fullcalendar.moment object

for example:

```
let d = $.fullCalendar.moment(dateString);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
```

I assume you are familiar with jquery, if you are not please let me know and I shall assist you further!

Comment: Actually I don't familiar with jquery (>_<")

Comment: Well if you have specific questions feel free to ask!